# How to stop parallax scrolling when at the top of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, intersection, parallax, threshold

I have a mountain parallax scene with four images within a container that parallax scroll when the container is visible within the viewport at the bottom of the screen. The animation works but the parallax starts to reverse when the container begins to leave the viewport at the top of the screen. You can see the working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/breonwilliams/n2tspLzk/12/

The script for the parallax is below. How can I stop the parallax scroll when the container div leaves the viewport?

```
  /**
   * Creates an IntersectionObserver and starts observing all elements found using the selector.
   *
   * @param {String} selector: Selector used to find all target elements
   * @param {Number[]} threshold: Array of intersection ratios, at which the callback is executed
   * @param {Function} callback: Callback executed for each threshold
   */
  function observe(selector, threshold, callback) {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    const options = {
      rootMargin: '-100px',
      threshold: threshold,
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

    for (const element of elements) {
      observer.observe(element);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a CSS translateY value.
   *
   * @param {Number} ratio: A number between 0 and 1
   * @param {String} total: A valid CSS number and unit (10px, 100%, 30vh, …)
   * @return {String} The CSS translateY value.
   */
  function translateY(ratio, total) {
    return `translateY(calc(-${ratio} * ${total})`;
  }

  /**
   * Callback executed for the box elements
   *
   * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
   *
   * @param {IntersectionObserverEntry[]} entries: Intersection Observer Entries
   * @param {IntersectionObserver} observer: Intersection Observer
   */
  function boxParallax(entries, observer) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-140px');
      }
    }
  }

  function boxParallax_two(entries, observer) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-270px');
      }
    }
  }

  function boxParallax_three(entries, observer) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-300px');
      }
    }
  }

  function boxParallax_four(entries, observer) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-350px');
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Create one threshold for each intersection ratio.
   *
   * @return {Number[]}
   */
  function createThreshold() {
    const threshold = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.01) {
      threshold.push(i);
    }

    return threshold;
  }

  const threshold = createThreshold();
  observe('.two', threshold, boxParallax);
  observe('.three', threshold, boxParallax_two);
  observe('.four', threshold, boxParallax_three);
  observe('.five', threshold, boxParallax_four);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

````
/**
 * Creates an IntersectionObserver and starts observing all elements found using the selector.
 *
 * @param {String} selector: Selector used to find all target elements
 * @param {Number[]} threshold: Array of intersection ratios, at which the callback is executed
 * @param {Function} callback: Callback executed for each threshold
 */
function observe(selector, threshold, callback) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const options = {
    rootMargin: '-100px',
    threshold: threshold,
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

  for (const element of elements) {
    observer.observe(element);
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a CSS translateY value.
 *
 * @param {Number} ratio: A number between 0 and 1
 * @param {String} total: A valid CSS number and unit (10px, 100%, 30vh, …)
 * @return {String} The CSS translateY value.
 */
function translateY(ratio, total) {
  return `translateY(calc(-${ratio} * ${total})`;
}

/**
 * Callback executed for the box elements
 *
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
 *
 * @param {IntersectionObserverEntry[]} entries: Intersection Observer Entries
 * @param {IntersectionObserver} observer: Intersection Observer
 */
function boxParallax(entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.boundingClientRect.top > 100) {
      entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-140px');
    }
  }
}

function boxParallax_two(entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.boundingClientRect.top > 100) {
      entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-270px');
    }
  }
}

function boxParallax_three(entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.boundingClientRect.top > 100) {
      entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-300px');
    }
  }
}

function boxParallax_four(entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.boundingClientRect.top > 100) {
      entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '-350px');
    }
  }
}
/**
 * Create one threshold for each intersection ratio.
 *
 * @return {Number[]}
 */
function createThreshold() {
  const threshold = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 0.5; i += 0.01) {
    threshold.push(i);
  }

  return threshold;
}

const threshold = createThreshold();
observe('.two', threshold, boxParallax);
observe('.three', threshold, boxParallax_two);
observe('.four', threshold, boxParallax_three);
observe('.five', threshold, boxParallax_four);

});```
````